# SwiftUI View ForEach loop from last to first

Tags: swiftui

How can I loop from last item to first in a SwiftUi view?

I've tried the following

```
let myarray = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
ForEach(stride(from: myarray.count, to: 1, by: -1), id: \.self) { i in
    print(myarray[i])
}

//desired output: 4 3 2 1
```

Thanks!!

Comment: ForEach is a View, not a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reversed`:

```
ForEach(myarray.reversed(), id: \.self) { item in
    Text("\(item)")
}
```

Note that I'm using `Text`, not `print` -- this is SwiftUI, so you should have `View` code inside a `ForEach`.

Also note that `\.self` is generally dangerous in `ForEach`, but I'm assuming this is just sample code. Generally, you want something truly uniquely `Identifiable`